# How to find and delete "other" contacts

Tags: gmail

How do I find and delete all the "other" contacts show up?  I have a boat load of those that no longer exist or are needed.

Answer (score 3):

To delete "Other Contacts" in Gmail: From the Contacts page:

1. Select "Other Contacts" on the left
2. Use the check box to select all contacts
3. Click "Delete Contacts" under the "More" menu

[image: DeleteOtherContactsGmail]